# How to use lottie speed to duration in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, lottie

I'm using this animation https://assets2.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_k5lht2yq.json.

For some reason , the duration prop not working.

```
<LottieView
          autoPlay={true}
          duration={60000}
          loop={false}
          source={assets.LOTTIE_LEVEL_PROGRESS}
          style={styles.lottie}
        />
```

As you can see, I'm trying to play animation for a 60 seconds, but in real time it playing about 4 seconds.

The lottie library contain speed prop that receives a number from 0 to 1.

Is there a way to play this anim for a 60 (dynamic number, may change to 120 seconds and more) seconds?

Comment: Are you sure that your json animation object is valid? Github page says `duration: the duration of the animation in ms. Takes precedence over speed when set. This only works when source is an actual JS object of an animation.`

Answer (score 0):

I think duration in this library means the ms that one animation takes in order to execute. So in your code, your animation execute only once and it takes 1 minutes. In other words it is so slow that you cant even see the execution. for execute your animation in normal speed for about 1m you need the following code:

```
function Example() {
  const [loop, setLoop] = useState(true);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      let timer = setTimeout(() => setLoop(false), 60000);
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      };
    },[]);

  return (
    <LottieView
        autoPlay
        loop={loop}
        source={assets.LOTTIE_LEVEL_PROGRESS}
        style={styles.lottie}
     />
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @molood ayat,

In this case, the animation will loop.

The animation is a progress bar that fills for a 5 seconds , and i need to change this duration from 5 to what ever i want =]

Comment: ooh in this case I think you can use state for your duration. But in my opinion if you write new one or use existing libraries such as react-native-progress can be more natural and desirable.